# Convert this C# code to functional equivalent

Tags: c#

I'm interested in converting this to a functional one-liner, and I think it would use either Select or Map but I can't get the syntax right.

```
Dictionary<String, String[]> orgIds = ...
Dictionary<Guid, String[]> orgGuids = new Dictionary<Guid, string[]>();
foreach (var pair in orgIds)
{
    orgGuids.Add(new Guid(pair.Key), pair.Value);
}
```

In case it's not clear, I'm starting with a Dictionary that maps strings to string arrays, and I need to convert the keys to GUIDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var orgGuids = orgIds.ToDictionary(x => new Guid(x.Key), x => x.Value);
```